Disabling edit mode in Jupyter Notebook
I have markdown cells in Jupyter Notebook, and I'd like to entirely disable edit mode. (That is, I find myself double clicking in order to select text to copy & paste, and then  cursing when it thinks I want to edit and moves everything around.)
I've already disabled editing via the metadata for the cell ("editable": false). That's a start. But is it possible to keep the silly thing from entering edit mode at all, and just treat the markdown as static text?
